# Environment specific pip.conf under anaconda

Tags: python, pip, conda

I'm working on a Python library and using the anaconda distribution.  I install packages into a `conda` environment with both `conda` and `pip`.  I'd like to install Python packages from both PyPi and an in-house repository server (Sonatype Nexus).  To do this I need to set the `--extra-index-url` flag.

I'd like to make this reproducible to enable anyone to recreate the environment from a script so setting `--extra-index-url` from a command line invocation of `pip` isn't an option.

I could set this globally in `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf`, which works, but this isn't transferrable to other users, at least not in an automated way.

Is there a way to set a `conda` environment specific `pip.conf` file?  Where would it be placed?  This would enable anyone to check out the library code and recreate the environment with all dependencies intact and pulling code from an internal repository?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set the environmental variable `PIP_CONFIG_FILE` and point to the `pip.conf` you like. Since you want

> to recreate the environment from a script

you could  set `PIP_CONFIG_FILE` in this script.

Comment: Can you link to a reference please?

Comment: No reference needed, @lostsoul29 , I don't think.  An *environment variable* is simply a variable that your command line can recognize.  If you were not doing it in a script, you would simply type `PIP_CONFIG_FILE='/full/path/to/pip.conf'` (on Mac or Linux, I think Windows is quite similar).  In a *Bash*, *ZSH*, or similarly Linux-like script, you would also put the same command, but within the script itself.  Finally, you can test that you did it right by typing `echo $PIP_CONFIG_FILE` at the command line to see that it was recorded.

Answer (score 4):

It might be worth mentioning that [Conda YAML environment definitions](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) support the full spectrum of the `pip install` arguments, including `--extra-index-url`. For example, one could have something like:

**environment.yaml**

```yaml
name: foo
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - numpy
  - scipy
  - pip
  - pip:
    - --extra-index-url https://127.0.100.55  # some custom URI
    - custom-pkg1
    - custom-pkg2
```

See Conda's [Advanced Pip Example](https://github.com/conda/conda/tree/master/tests/conda_env/support/advanced-pip) for a showcase of other capabilities.