# How to add a non-pypi dependency to requirements?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, conda, setuptools

I have a package that can be installed this way using `pip`:

```
pip install -I http://corporate.domain/url --trusted-host corporate.domaine project_name
```

I develop locally using PyCharm and a Conda environment.

Then, I fetch the code remotely on AWS, where I need to install all the required packages.

I tried using PyCharm's "Sync Python Requirements" feature but it doesn't seem to work:

- it doesn't seem to work with Conda (especially if I try to use things like ~=)
- some packages are not added to the file (they continue to be underlined but no matter how many times I click "add", they are not added - interestingly, the imports are still underlined when I add the dependencies manually to `requirements.txt`)
- Some packages don't come from PyPi so I need to convey somehow where to get them

I would like to continue using Conda locally because it works fine and it's very convenient. I don't mind whether to use Conda or Pip or whatever else on AWS as long as it works and it's easy to sync these requirements going forward.

Would also love to know if there is a way for PyCharm to update the requirements file without me having to trigger this manually every time.

I tried looking into `setup.py` but I didn't quite understand whether it solves this problem or something else (there seems to be a lot of focus on publishing to PyPi).

I don't really need to install my own project as a package, I am fine with running it "from source" by pulling from git etc.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69579003/570918) is probably relevant. I could imagine if you need to isolate particular external packages, they could go in their own `requirements.txt` file, and use a `- -r requirements.txt` to install it. BTW, I think you mean `-i <url>`; the `-I` flag means something else.

Answer (score 1):

`pip` silently ignores the presence of `dependency_links` since version 19, with the functionality moved to `install_requires`, like so:

```
setup(
...
install_requires=['package_name@custom_url'],
...
)
```

For example, to use my fork of `foobar` hosted on GitHub:

```
setup(
...
install_requires=['foobar@git+http://github.com/snowskeleton/foobar'],
...
)
```